# Can't locate enemy-territory in terminal?

Tags: 10.10, apt, games

I have an issue trying to install True Combat: Elite.

I followed these **[steps](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10063534&postcount=4)**, But when I do the 4th step, I get this:

`E: Unable to locate package enemy-territory`

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems my problems were caused by old playdeb repositories that were *disabled* when I upgraded to 10.10.

The solution was to:

- make sure ubuntu software center is closed and remove playdeb package via synaptic

  1. Open up Synaptic (by going to System → Administration → Synaptic Package Manager)
  2. Search for "playdeb" and select "mark for complete removal"
  3. Apply the changes and close synaptic
- Install the playdeb package again
- update and install the game via the terminal.

  1. `sudo apt-get update`
  2. `sudo apt-get install enemy-territory`

I also removed all the old playdeb repositories from the software sources by opening the software center, going to *Edit → Software-Sources → Other Software* and removing the disabled entries.

Answer (score 3):

**Installation Steps**

1. Install the package to add PlayDeb PPA from **[here](http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/playdeb_0.3-1%7Egetdeb1_all.deb)**.
2. Run the following commands to install Enemy Territory,

   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install enemy-territory`
3. Start Enemy Territory once and create a User.
4. Download **[True Combat Elite 0.49](http://www.filefront.com/6002126/True-Combat-Elite-.049/)** and the **[0.49b Patch](http://www.truecombatelite.com/files/tce049b_all_os_fixed.zip)**.
5. Extract TCE 0.49 and put the Folder "tcetest" in `/home/yourusername/.etwolf`
6. Extract the TCE 0.49b Patch and put the Content of the Folder in the `tcetest` Folder.
7. Now TCE should be listed as a Mod in Enemy Territory.
8. Run the Mod.

**Note:**

- After completing the first step the .deb file will be placed inside your home directory.
- Double click the .deb file to install it and then follow the second step.

Comment: still says the same thing for step 2

Comment: What version of ubuntu you are using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: I have tested in ubuntu 10.10 and it is working for me.

Comment: Well it doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: Can you post the output of the following commands in a pastebin, `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: It doesn't fit. :(

Comment: Goto [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and paste your results there.And give us the link.

Comment: Never knew they had a site like that. But here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/548447/

Comment: Both are two different commands enter the command one by one in your terminal and then post the output.

Comment: Okay, here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/548448/ and here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/548449/

Comment: Backup you sources.list file and try using this http://paste.ubuntu.com/548451/

Comment: How do I back it up?

Comment: Okay. I'm there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the installation via [PlayDeb.net](http://www.playdeb.net/updates/ubuntu/10.10/) ? They have pretty straightforward instructions there how to install games from their site and Enemy Territory is included on their site.

Basically it does just the same as described above but prevents any mistakes you might have done during the installation.